# Updating previous installation settings

Tags: file, inno-setup, updates, uninstallation

I'm creating an update setup files. In my initial installation, I have an EXE file which is called in [UninstallRun]. In the update, I want to permanently remove this EXE file but it seems to always throw the error "Some elements could not be removed" when I uninstall after the update.

To delete the EXE, I've tried deleting it during the update's `[InstallDelete]`. This deletes the file, but the error message is still thrown when its uninstalled (even though all files have definitely been removed).

I tried replacing the EXE in the update and using the `deleteafterinstall` flag, but that didn't make a difference.

If I don't do anything, and just install it, when I run the uninstaller, the EXE file is called, even though the update no longer contains the `[UninstallRun]` section. So it looks like the initial installation's setup file is being used for the uninstallation part.

For the purposes of this project, I can't change the initial installation, so everything has to be done from the update installation. Is there a way to delete an existing file that was placed in an `UninstallRun` section?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that the `[UninstallRun]` entry from the prior install has already been registered in the uninstall log, so simply removing it from your script won't stop it taking effect, and deleting the file will by default make it generate that error since (presumably) some required uninstall task didn't happen since the file was missing.

Did you remember to put a `RunOnceId` on the `[UninstallRun]` entry in the original installer?  If so, you can put a "replacement" entry using the same id.  You'll still have to make it point at an exe, but you can make it a no-op one, or (better) use `Flags: skipifdoesntexist` and point it at the one you've removed.

If you didn't use a `RunOnceId`, then there isn't any way to override the previous entry.  You'll just have to put in a dummy exe file that does nothing.

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't put a RunOnceId so I'll have to put a dummy file. Will this be the case for all future updates, or is it possible to put something in the second update that will allow me to remove it in a future one? Thanks

Comment: If you put a RunOnceId in the first update then you will be able to override that in the second update -- but if someone goes straight from the original install to the second update, you're faced with the same problem again.  So you'll never be able to get rid of it entirely.  (Note also that forgetting the RunOnceId also means that it may end up getting run more than once, if the user ran the original installer multiple times.)